# Как сделать Pie Chart в Android на языке Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Моей целью является создание Pie Chart диаграммы используя библиотеку MPAndroidChart. Мой код на саму диаграмму:

```
class results_activity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results_activity)

    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.close)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    setUpPieChartData()
}

private fun setUpPieChartData() {
    val yVals = ArrayList<PieEntry>()
    yVals.add(PieEntry(30f))
    yVals.add(PieEntry(2f))
    yVals.add(PieEntry(4f))
    yVals.add(PieEntry(22f))
    yVals.add(PieEntry(12.5f))

    val dataSet = PieDataSet(yVals, "")
    dataSet.valueTextSize=0f
    val colors = java.util.ArrayList<Int>()
    colors.add(Color.GRAY)
    colors.add(Color.BLUE)
    colors.add(Color.RED)
    colors.add(Color.GREEN)
    colors.add(Color.MAGENTA)

    dataSet.setColors(colors)
    val data = PieData(dataSet)
    idPieChart.data = data
    idPieChart.centerTextRadiusPercent = 0f
    idPieChart.isDrawHoleEnabled = false
    idPieChart.legend.isEnabled = false
    idPieChart.description.isEnabled = false
}
```

А проблема заключается в том, что у меня каждый раз высвечивается ошибка "No chart data available". Но я ни каких ошибок не заметил. Как можно эту проблему исправить?